# Google Cloud Dataflow Custom Keys with common functionality

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We are using the Dataflow Java SDK and we have an increasing number of custom key classes that are almost the same.

I would like to have them extend a common abstract class however the Dataflow SDK seems to try to instantiate the abstract class causing an InstantiationException.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.newInstance(SpecificData.java:316)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.newRecord(SpecificData.java:332)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:173)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:151)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:142)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.AvroCoder.decode(AvroCoder.java:242)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.KvCoder.decode(KvCoder.java:97)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.KvCoder.decode(KvCoder.java:42)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromSafeStream(CoderUtils.java:156)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:139)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:133)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.MutationDetectors$CodedValueMutationDetector.<init>(MutationDetectors.java:108)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.MutationDetectors.forValueWithCoder(MutationDetectors.java:45)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo$ImmutabilityCheckingOutputManager.output(ParDo.java:1218)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:329)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:483)
    at com.telstra.cdf.rmr.model.pardos.ParDoAbstractCampaignUAKeyExtractor.processElement(ParDoAbstractCampaignUAKeyExtractor.java:5
```

here is our abstract class,

```
@DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
public abstract class SuperClassKey  {
    public SuperClassKey(){}
    public abstract double getSomeValue();
}
```

and this is the sub class

```
@DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
public class SubClassKey extends SuperClassKey {
    public String foo;

    public SubClassKey() {
    }

    public SubClassKey(String foo){
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        SubClassKey that = (SubClassKey) o;

        if (!foo.equals(that.foo)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return foo.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public double getSomeValue() {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

I have also tried using an interface without success.

Is it possible to have a common abstract class or interface between Keys?

Comment: I would expect this to work (without any annotations or zero-arg constructors on the abstract base class), as long as the PCollection is typed with the concrete class. E.g., `PCollection<SuperClassKey>` would not work, but `PCollection<SubClassKey>` would, using, for example, a `.setCoder(AvroCoder.of(SubClassKey.class))` if the inference does not. Can you say more about how you instantiated the PCollections?

Comment: Thanks, the issue was that I was creating a PCollectinon<SuperClassKey>.

Comment: Hi Darren! Do you mind posting this as an answer? For posterity and so that whoever runs into this issue in the future can find a solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely from using a `PCollection<SuperClassKey>` instead of `PCollection<SubClassKey>`.  The PCollection needs to be typed with a concrete class.  The coder can be explicitly specified with `.setCoder(AvroCoder.of(SubClassKey.class))` if type inference is not sufficient.

Comment: This is really annoying when trying to call the subclasses in a polymorphic way. Is there any better way of handling key value classes?

Comment: We'll look at if there's a better way to support this more elegantly; glad the solution is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my canse, i changed the Coder class, example:

Before:

```
AvroIO.parseGenericRecords(RecordConverter::convert)
 .withCoder(AvroCoder.of(Struct.class)).from(...)
```

After:

```
AvroIO.parseGenericRecords(RecordConverter::convert)
 .withCoder(SerializableCoder.of(Struct.class)).from(...)
```